# Regular Expression library/set to parse sql

Tags: sql, regex, parsing

Anyone know of any re libraries out there to help parse columns, functions, and values from an SQL WHERE clause?

Example strings:

```
COLUMN=='VALUE'
COLUMN=='VALUE' AND COLUMN2='VALUE'
FUNCTION(COLUMN)==FUNCTION('VALUE')
```

I'm working in Python, but can port most anything over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394998/parsing-sql-with-python) SO question and its answers will help (Parsing SQL with Python).

[Here](http://www.python.org/workshops/1995-05/sql.html) [are](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/620387) a couple of links that may help.