# Regex to capture CTEs

Tags: python, regex, common-table-expression

I've built this regex to capture snowflake CTEs.
The CTEs are defined by a first WITH reserved keyword, but the next ones need only an AS. Here's an example:

```
WITH first_rows AS (select top 3 * from table1), other_rows AS (select * from table 2), yet_other_rows AS (select top 2 from another_table)
Select x, y z 
from top_rows inner join other_rows on field1=field2
              inner join yetother_rows on field1=field2
```

Then a with clause with CTEs can be anywhere in the SQL as it can also be used in subqueries.

The regex I wrote captures a couple of CTE names only ignoring most of the remaining ones. What's wrong with this regex

```
(?:.*?)with\s+(\w+)\s+as.*?(?:\,\s+(\w+)\s+as\s+.*)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can make this work. You can have almost anything inside the CTE, including use of the word `as` as well as nested parentheses. You need an SQL parser.

Comment: Would every CTE definition always reside on just one line?

Comment: What is what you want to find? is it the whole chunk from the first with until the end of the chunk?

Comment: I want to get the cte names

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not necessarily, but I can make it so if needed

Comment: @Nick any resources to learn how I can use a SQL parser programmatically?

Comment: Lots of info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394998/parsing-sql-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is a task for a proper SQL parser.  That being said, if we assume that *only* CTE definitions would start with a word-name followed by `AS`, a space, and `(`, then we can try the following approach:

```py
import re

inp = """WITH first_rows AS (select top 3 * from table1), other_rows AS (select * from table 2), yet_other_rows AS (select top 2 from another_table)
Select x, y z 
from top_rows inner join other_rows on field1=field2
              inner join yetother_rows on field1=field2"""

names = re.findall(r'(\w+) AS \(', inp)
print(names)  # ['first_rows', 'other_rows', 'yet_other_rows']
```

Comment: thanks but the first instance needs a WITH before, while the other instances don't need it

Comment: Not necessarily.  `AS` followed by `(` may be unique enough in your code that it would only belong to a CTE name.

Comment: It doesn't solve the overall concern, but it seems to be due to a regex limitation. However it solves my problem and it deserves to be the best answer. Thanks