# Need to parse sql with reg exp

Tags: python, sql, regex, plsql, python-re

I need to delete any condition associated with date from "where" block from pl sql query. I use python re library and re.sub() function.
Ass rexp pattern, I've wrote this regular expression:
`((?<=where)|(?<=and))[^()]*?\w*date\w*.*?((and)|(?=order|where|left|right|inner|join|full))`

And this is an example where it works not correct:
https://regex101.com/r/HMAWI8/1

As you can check, with this pattern part:  `a.f_funid = b.f_funid and`, are selected for some reason as part of a larger match `a.f_funid = b.f_funid and a.begin_date <= to_date('11.11.1111 01:00:50','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and` despite of `and` part which should separate it, in my opinion. And I can't get why it ignoring first `and` part.

As result i want to get this row:

```
select any from (select any from some where a.f_funid = b.f_funid) r left join ods.account_h a on r.f_account_id = a.f_account_id where r.f_picture in (select r.f_picture from ods.RELATION_h r, ods.CALENDAT_h c, ods.REV_h rev where c.F_REVALUATIONID = rev.F_REVALUATIONID) and lower(f_name) = 'smth') and  union all
```

I tried to use negative lookaround instead of `.*?` and `[^()]` parts, but seems it's a wrong way to solve this. I'm at a dead end right now.

Comment: SQL is a non-regular grammar, ergo it cannot be correctly parsed with RegEx or any other regular grammar. See pertinent answer on XHTML https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997 Also that's not even valid SQL.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." Regex is great, but for parsing sql by the time you've sorted out all the edge cases which are theoretically possible to sort out with regular expressions you could have manually done everything.

Comment: While the duplicate I link to is for XHTML, the answer is the same: SQL isn't a regular language and therefore can't be parsed with a regular expression.

Comment: Did you try to use the [SQLparse python package](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) ?
You also may find other options for parsing SQL in the answers of this [Parsing SQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394998/parsing-sql-with-python)